# Copy file to another virtual host

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, ssh, scp

I'm gonna copy file to virtual ubuntu via:

```
scp -r hadoop hadoop-slave-1:/opt/hadoop
```

But I get the error below:

```
ssh: connect to host hadoop-slave-1 port 22: Connection timed out
```

lost connection
I installed ssh on master and slave nodes. Actually, I want to do hadoop configuration via [hadoop config](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_multi_node_cluster.htm) but i don't make the connection between nodes. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have installed `openssh-server` on `hadoop-slave-1`? Do you have active firewall on `hadoop-slave-1` with some rule that allow inbound connection on port `22`? Do you master host known on witch 'ip address` is your `hadoop-slave-1`? what say output from command `host hadoop-slave-1` on master? Give us output from command `ss -l4n` executed on `hadoop-slave-1`.

Comment: Yes, I installed `openssh-server` on all of the nodes. As I activated firewall.  assigned ip address to slave nodes and put to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: output for both `host hadoop-slave-1` and ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`host myhostname` is : `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. `

Comment: You can resolve names of servers. Try  with `dig` command. `dig -t any hadoop-slave-1' If got ip, try to shutdown firewall and then try `ssh`